# Coefficients of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with real part of all roots negetive.

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I am reading [this paper](http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v33/cjm1981v33.1055-1059.pdf) in which for Theorem 2 they have used the following claim

**Claim** : Given  $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $Re({\alpha}_i) < b-0.5$ then $g(x+b-0.5)$ has no missing term (By term I think they mean coefficients of polynomial $g(x)$) and all the terms have same sign.

Also, the coefficients of  $g(-x+b-0.5)$ are strictly alternating.Thus,$$|g(b-0.5-t)|<|g(b-0.5+t)| \quad \forall t>0 $$

The paper says it is trivial.I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: I think I got it now the basic idea is "Since root comes in conjugate pairs,  the real part will decide modulus and sign of coefficients"

Comment: Exactly, and the point of the translation is to make the new roots have real part negative. The signs then alternate as odd degree terms will alternate upon their substitution. The last claim then follows because now every other term goes the "opposite" direction so the modulus decreases.